# Comparing Columns from 2 Tables With Where Clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have the following statement which is resulting in no results:

```
SELECT 
    temp_manual_pickups.PO,
    temp_manual_pickups.INVOICE,
    elite_routes.SOURCE,
    elite_routes.SOURCE_UDID,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_UDID,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_CITY,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_STATE,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_ZIP,
    elite_routes.SOURCE AS 'ORDER_BY',
    temp_manual_pickups.ZONE,
    temp_manual_pickups.PART_NUMBER,
    temp_manual_pickups.PART_DESCRIPTION,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_CITY,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_STATE,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_ZIP
FROM
    temp_manual_pickups,
    elite_routes
WHERE
    temp_manual_pickups.zone = elite_routes.route;
```

If I run the 2 statements below:

```
SELECT * FROM elite_routes
WHERE ROUTE = 4
```

Results

```
route, source, source_udid
4   FBP Doylestown - Main   C-Warehouse
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_MANUAL_PICKUPS
where zone = 4
```

Results

```
PO, INVOICE, DESTINATION, DESTINATION_UDID, DESTINATION_ADDRESS, DESTINATION_CITY, DESTINATION_STATE, DESTINATION_ZIP, ZONE, PART_NUMBER, PART_DESCRIPTION, ship_to, ship_to_address, ship_to_city, ship_to_state, ship_to_zip
NEW RETURN-G    PU-203151   MAGARITY AUTO   Z3422285    7972 ROCKWELL AVE   PHILADELPHIA    PA  19111-2223  4
    68286732AA  BRACKET-RADIATOR SUPPORT                    
NEW RETURN-G    PU-203151   MAGARITY AUTO   Z3422285    7972 ROCKWELL AVE   PHILADELPHIA    PA  19111-2223  4
    68288334AA  BRACKET-SUPPORT FRONT                   
NEW RETURN-G    PU-203151   MAGARITY AUTO   Z3422285    7972 ROCKWELL AVE   PHILADELPHIA    PA  19111-2223  4
    68225214AA  CLIP-FASCIA
```

When I run the 2 statements individually, it is clear that both of the tables have the "4" in the respective columns, but when I compare them in the where clause, I get no results.  Do I have an error in syntax somehwhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a JOIN to perform a query joining data from multiple tables.

Here is your query with a left join:

```sql
SELECT 
    temp_manual_pickups.PO,
    temp_manual_pickups.INVOICE,
    elite_routes.SOURCE,
    elite_routes.SOURCE_UDID,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_UDID,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_ADDRESS,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_CITY,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_STATE,
    temp_manual_pickups.DESTINATION_ZIP,
    elite_routes.SOURCE AS 'ORDER_BY',
    temp_manual_pickups.ZONE,
    temp_manual_pickups.PART_NUMBER,
    temp_manual_pickups.PART_DESCRIPTION,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_CITY,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_STATE,
    temp_manual_pickups.SHIP_TO_ZIP
FROM
    temp_manual_pickups
LEFT JOIN 
    elite_routes
ON 
    temp_manual_pickups.zone = elite_routes.route;
```

Some documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: I need to use the `elite_routes` in the `FROM` statement because I am pulling info from that table as well.

Comment: Do you get any data when doing the left join query though? Otherwise your query should work fine, you don't get any error? Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I do get the "correct" data, it is missing the info from the 3 columns from `elite_route` though.  MySQL version is 5.7.21

Comment: I  figured it out, my original statement was fine, the was a carriage return in the `temp_manual_pickups.zone` field, so I added an `UPDATE` and `TRIM` function